# Tangential Circles connecting Oriented Points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, tangent-line, orientation

I have two arbitrary points (A and B) in a plane, and I'm working in cartesian coordinates.

Each of these points has an associated arbitrary unit direction vector - so from point A, for example, I want to travel in direction U - and from point B, I want to travel in direction V.

I would like to travel out from both of these points, following a circular path that is tangent to the associated direction vector at that point.

There can be either 1 (in some cases) or 2 circles, but the circles should meet when their tangents match, so the resulting curve between the two points is everywhere differentiable.

Usually I want the radius of these circles to match, but it would be better if I could define a ratio between them.

This is very similar to this question: [Connecting two tangents with two circles of equal radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149126/connecting-two-tangents-with-two-circles-of-equal-radius)

Except for the addition of the radius ratio.

My approach for solving this so far has been:

1. The circle assocaited with point A will have a center that lies on a line orthogonal to U, the vector direction associated with A.
2. The circle associated with point B will similarly have a center that lies on a line orthogonal to V, the vector direction associated with B.
3. Solve for A + r*U = B + r*V = 2r

However there are a couple problems with this approach:

1. I don't think this will account for the ratio constraint (I'm not sure if that CAN be enforced)
2. I'm not sure if it's mathematically consistent with what direction I need to travel along the orthogonal-to-the-direction-vector vector: for instance, if I travel -r units along one vector but +r units along the second vector, will the quadratic still work to solve for R?

This is not to mention the fact that I've apparently messed up the programming and it's not giving me the answers I expect... I'll keep trying on that front, but I would really appreciate input on the above 2 points.

Comment: You want to travel on a circle path connecting A and B.  So it is one circle not two.  There is no radius ratio, because it is one circle only by your description.

Comment: Traveling from each point, I follow a circular path that is tangent to a specified vector: in some special cases a single circle may satisfy both vectors/point positions, but in most cases it will need to be 2.

Comment: I suppose you mean $|(A + rU') - (B + rV')| = 2r$, where $U'$ and $V'$ are perpendicular to $U$ and $V$.  If radii are in the ratio of $k$, just solve instead: $|(A + rU') - (B + krV')| = (1+k)r$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca That looks correct, but I worry there are situations where it might not give sensible answers: I'm not sure if, mathematically, solving with a given ratio is always possible?

Comment: One solution is always guaranteed. Suppose your two circles start growing from $r=0$,  keeping a fixed ratio between them. Sooner or later they'll collide and at that moment they'll be externally tangent. Of course you must choose a correct orientation for $U'$ and $V'$, of the four possible. There might be more solutions, in some particular cases.